# USB modem does not connect as ethernet on hub

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, usb-modem, modem-manager

I have 4.5G Usb Modem (VINN), it sees this modem directly to my computer as ethernet. (SS 1)
[image: Screenshot1]

But when combined with a USB hub, it doesn't see it as ethernet (SS2). What could be the reason?
[image: Screenshot2]

- It sees when you plug in a 3G USB modem from the same USB multiplexer.
- When I plug in USB HUB 4.G Vınn over Windows, it is successful.
- After seeing the device on Windows, when it restarts and switches to the linux machine via boot, it again sees it as Ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem with usb_modeswitch

/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/alcatel.conf;

```
DefaultVendor=  0x1bbb
DefaultProduct= 0xf000

TargetVendor=   0x1bbb
TargetProduct=  0x0017

MessageContent="55534243123456788000000080000606f50402527000000000000000000000"
#MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000"
```

after run ;

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 1bbb -p f000 -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/alcatel.conf
```